# WebKit browsers showing off colors for HTML5 videos

Tags: html, google-chrome, video, mp4

I am trying to display a video on a webpage using HTML5 and an MP4 file.  The video displays and plays fine, but there are issues with the colors on certain devices.

The video sits on a background color of `#dcdcdc`.  The video's background is also `#dcdcdc`.  On my machine (Windows 7, Chrome) the colors match.  On my iMac in Chrome the background does *not* match and is a slightly lighter shade of grey.  On a colleagues machine (Windows 7, Chrome) the background does *not* match and is the same as the iMac.

I have set up a JSFiddle of the video, with the background: http://jsfiddle.net/xym9znzc/1/

I'd like to remind you that this *does* look fine on my machine, but doesn't on the majority of others.